# Empty Variable for lambda SingleOrDefault()

Tags: c#, lambda, variable-assignment

I want to declare empty variable for this condition,

```
 if(........)
 {
  emptyIQueryable= DBContext.MyTables.Join(MyTableTwos , x => x.ID , i => i.TID ,      ((x,i)  => 
  new{
      x,i
     }
  )).Where(x => x.ID == 1).SingleOrDefault();
  }
  else
  {
   emptyIQueryable= DBContext.MyTables.Join(MyTableTwos , x => x.ID , i => i.TID , ((x,i)  => 
  new{
     x,i
     }
  )).Where(x => x.ID == 2).SingleOrDefault();
  }
```

How can I declare it ?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Try rephrasing your question.

Comment: `MyTable emptyIQueryable;` should compile (with bad naming), the result of `SingleOrDefault` is not an `IQueryable` of any kind.

Comment: @zey what do you mean "it cannot be"?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I think he means it won't compile :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SingleOrDefault` does not return an `IQueryable` - it returns the object that `MyTables` consists of, or null. So if `MyTables` contains several objects of type say `MyTable`, that is the type for your variable:

```
MyTable result;
if(........)
{
    result = DBContext.MyTables.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1);
}
else
{
    result = DBContext.MyTables.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == 2);
}
```

**Update.** After edit thing get more complicated. The expression you are using returns object of type `IEnumerable<anonymous>`, which is impossible to state in code explicitly. You can, however, use either `object` or `IEnumerable` for `emptyIQueryable`, but you will loose some info about the object either way.

However this code can be easily refactored to get rid of the problem completely:

```
Func<MyTable, bool> condition;
if (.....)
{
    condition = x => x.ID == 1;
}
else
{
    condition = x => x.ID == 2;
}

var emptyIQueryable =
         DBContext.MyTables
                  .Join(MyTableTwos, x => x.ID, i => i.TID, ((x,i) => new {x,i}))
                  .Where(condition).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: +1 and Thanks Andrei , I've edit my question . How can I do it if I joined Two tables ?

Comment: @Andrei: It's actually not impossible to declare a variable as an anonymous type.  See my answer.  I don't recommend using that technique, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to declare a variable as being an anonymous type without assigning to it.  It's kind of a trick of the compiler, but you can do it like this.

```
var emptyIQueryable = false 
    ? new { x = default(MyTable), i = default(MyTableTwo) } 
    : null;
```

`emptyIQueryable` is assigned to null, and that anonymous object is never constructed.  But it has the exact some IL type as you create later.  The compiler guarantees that any two anonymously typed objects created in the same method that have the same properties with the same types in the same order will have the same type.  Therefore, you could assign to it in your if block later.